# Extracting two strings using `-match`

Tags: regex, powershell

I am attempting to parse the string:

```
helo identity email@test.com Pass (v=spf1)
```

using `-match` as follows:

```
$line -match "helo identity (?<sender>.*) (?<heloresult>.*) (v=spf1)"
```

I would think this would return:

```
$matches['sender'] = "email@test.com"
$matches['heloresult'] = "Pass"
```

However, it returns `$false`.

Worth noting that the following works as expected:

```
$line -match "helo identity (?<sender>.*) Pass"
PS C:\> $matches
Name                           Value
----                           -----
sender                         email@test.com
0                              helo identity email@test.com Pass
```

What am I doing incorrectly to assign these two parts?

Comment: I think you should escape the parenthesis in `(v=spf1)` the correct regex would be: `helo identity (?<sender>.*) (?<heloresult>.*) \(v=spf1\)`

Comment: I agree @fardjad , you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer as [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165892/extracting-two-strings-using-match/34166028#comment56079089_34165892):

`(` and `)` are special characters in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) regular expressions. Literal parenthesis must be escaped with backslashes. The correct RegEx in your case would be:

```
helo identity (?<sender>.*) (?<heloresult>.*) \(v=spf1\)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works! https://gist.github.com/mbrownnycnyc/4ed056431664575a0a77

Answer (score 3):

Escape the capturing parentheses around the last v=spf1 part to make them literal parentheses. Escape using a backslash, the regex escape character.

```
PS C:\temp> 'helo identity email@test.com Pass (v=spf1)' -match 'helo identity (?<Sender>.*) (?<HeloResult>.*) \(v=spf1\)'
True

PS C:\temp> $Matches.Values
email@test.com
Pass
helo identity email@test.com Pass (v=spf1)
```